# Node / HAPI: Too many simultaneous connections causes network connections to be reset

Tags: node.js, networking, tcp, hapi.js

A Node server uses HAPI to create its REST api. A growing number of connections is targetting this system until the point where more & more connections are "reset", causing an error on the client side.

First attempt was to look for synchronous ("blocking"?) request handlers, but everything requiring filsystem / external systems access is already made asynchronous.

My best guess is that Node (or HAPI) is designed in a way that requests are assigned to a socket (?) and until the response is sent, that socket is "blocked". There is perhaps a maximum open socket count. I'm looking for clues... thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Windows servers limit the number of active sockets according to memory available (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739169(v=vs.85).aspx). Non-servers have hard limits. Don´t know about other OSs.